# The ends of the brackets

Tags: symbols

Normally:

[image]

When I use the `\big[`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
\big[
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: There is a problem at the ends of the square brackets @Mico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a consequence of the fonts you have chosen.  Note that the fact that `\big` is usable in text mode is an accident of the implementation, and it uses math fonts, the intended markup would be `$\bigl[$` and even if used as you show uses the math fonts (so mnsymbol here)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
[\big[
\end{document}
```

the first [ is

```
....\T1/phv/m/n/10 [
```

so [ from helvetica (or most likely the URW helvetica clone) where the top bars are straight.

The second one is

```
.......\OMX/MnSymbolE/m/n/10 ^^B
```

So a character from the Mnsymbol math fonts which have curved inner edges to the [ character.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to fix this issue with this font or is it not changing because of the font @David Carlisle

Comment: @suarez don't use `\usepackage{mathastext}` and use input of `$[ \big[$` then you get consistent math fonts from mnsymbol.